# Acer Aspire 4820tg Graphic card driver

Tags: drivers, video

My ATI Radeon Video Card still has quite bad performance in Ubuntu 11.04
My Laptop is Acer Aspire 4820TG 
My Graphic card is ATI MOBILITY RADEON 5650

Answer (score 2):

I have that laptop too. I couldn't get that Radeon to works well on my Ubuntu, so I **completely powered off it** following that guide:

> https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Acer_Aspire_TimelineX_4820TG#Switchable_Graphics

My battery duration went from the previous 3h30 to the current 6h+. I suggest you to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you can achieve a better performance than by using the open source drivers and vgaswitcheroo (like lorenzo-s said). Sadly the 4820TG's graphics card still comes with a MUX that is not supported by the proprietary AMD drivers. The last driver that worked was fglrx 11.8 which was developed for 10.04. For all newer versions, switching with MUX was disabled and it is not likely that AMD will ever come up with a driver for that again.